# sql query not working dont know why

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have been awake for way to long and was hoping somebody could help me fix this query before i go

```sql
UPDATE Patrons SET name="Paul Mafinger", ADdress="88 Crazy Street", [Phone(H)]="24767536", hone(M)="6345735467", HomeBranch="Manly", Classification="Adult" WHERE MemberID="3973-6726-6813-1091"
```

and the error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `'Phone(H)="24767536", hone(M)="6345735467", HomeBranch="Manly", Classificatio'` at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySQL escape character is the back quote, not square braces.  Also, use single quotes for strings.  Double quotes can get confused with column names:

```
UPDATE Patrons
    SET name = 'Paul Mafinger',
        Address = '88 Crazy Street',
        `Phone(H)` = '24767536',
        `phone(M)` = '6345735467',
         HomeBranch = 'Manly',
         Classification = 'Adult'
     WHERE MemberID = '3973-6726-6813-1091';
```

I would recommend you name the columns with "normal" characters, so they don't even need to be escaped.  Something like `HomePhone` and `MobilePhone`.

Comment: Is this a malicious downvote or did I miss something?

Comment: thanks I normally would this is for an assignment the reason I wasn't using double quotes was because it was in java and out of habit I use double quotes in it.

Changed it thanks for that

Comment: @Paul . . . Double quotes work.  It is just that they can behave unexpectedly, because the string is first interpreted as a column and then as a constant.  This leads to problems in code -- problems which can be avoided just by using single quotes (the ANSI standard delimiter for strings).

Answer (score 0):

Appears as if it should be:

```
UPDATE Patrons SET name='Paul Mafinger', ADdress='88 Crazy Street', `[Phone(H)]`='24767536', hone(M)='6345735467', HomeBranch='Manly', Classification='Adult' WHERE MemberID='3973-6726-6813-1091'
```

Your phone record has characters that are used in `SQL` syntax, and so you can tell `SQL` that it is an identifier by surrounding it with ` characters.

`[Phone(H)]='24767536'`

Was changed to:

```
`[Phone(H)]`='24767536'
```

You can see how `[Phone(H)=]` is eclosed with `` characters It should also be noted that in SQL, you should be using single quotes rather than double quotes for specifying `String` values.